# Long running connection as part of my Django app

Tags: django, websocket

I would like to have a websocket **client** connection as part of my Django app. I want to listen to events and do stuff with those inside my Django world.

Is there a clean way to pack something like that into the app startup? Do I put it in `asgi.py` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Django does not have native support for websocket. You can use the Django Channel library to work with WS, but this is a very large library. Usually, in such cases, it is better to use aiohttp as a server, where all year you can fit in 100 lines and some sort of WS client.

https://pypi.org/project/channels/

https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/

https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/

Comment: Sure, I can add any other server to connect to the websocket but how then do I talk to the rest of my Django stuff?

Comment: I'll get events from the socket which will then require using logic from my django app and database read/writes.

Comment: To work with the database, you can use SQLAlchemy and aiohttp, if you are more comfortable with the more complicated solution on Channels, then you can use it. There are no other options for full Django and WS compatibility besides Channels.